# Как правильно подключить смартфон в android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Напишите пожалуйста подробно как подключить смартфон в качестве виртуального устройства чтобы запускать программы сразу с android studio
имею смартфон:
xiaomi redmi note 4x
android 7.0.1 (nougat)

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот устройство отображается но к нему подключиться невозможно

Comment: Воткнуть кабель, разрешить дебаг и установку приложений из других источников. С чем возникла проблема?

Comment: разрешить дебаг и установку приложений из других источников?

Answer (score 2):

Со смартфонами от Xiaomi нужно делать ещё кое что. Вам нужно попасть в раздел "Для разработчика" ВКЛючить там "Отладка по USB" и ВЫКЛючить там же "Оптимизация MIUI" перезагрузить телефон и попробовать запустить. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Итак, процесс подключения смартфона довольно простой и не требует много времени. Как уже написал `@Эникейщик` нужно воткнуть кабель и дальше по пунктам)) Если по порядку:

1. На смартфоне, независимо от производителя, модели, года производства и версии ос, нужно зайти в меню настроек. Дальше вы переходите в пункт списка "Для разработчиков" и разрешаете отладку по usb.
2. Дальше вы подключаете телефон к ПК.
3. Нажимаете в AS на зеленый треугольник для запуска приложения на устройстве и дальше в выбранном окошке выбираете ваш телефон.

Что может пойти не так:

1. Нет пункта меню "Для разработчиков". Довольно распространенная проблема и решается очень просто - вам нужно перейти в пункт меню "Об устройстве" и там найти номер сборки и несколько раз (много не нужно, но и пять раз наверное не хватит) нажать на нем, пока не получите сообщение о том что вы стали разработчиком. (лично у меня так)
2. Компьютер или AS не видит телефон - для этого установите драйвера или обновите их. Иногда производители смартфонов прошивают в телефоне установщик драйверов и у вас должен автоматом запустится процесс установки.

Вот подобный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947834/how-to-test-android-apps-in-a-real-device-with-android-studio) и вот еще [один](https://javatutorial.net/connect-android-device-android-studio).

Надеюсь что помог в решении вашей проблемы. Если что-то будет непонятно или возникнут сложности, с радостью поможем. Удачи :)